# What are some efficient LaTeX fonts? (fonts that are readable at small sizes/don't take up a lot of space)

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I am trying to find a font that is readable at small sizes.
Basically I need to squeeze many things together in a small space.  However I am unable to find much information available about what fonts are available for LaTeX that are good at this task.

Comment: I think the question requires clarification as it completely depends on your application. Some fonts that may be very readable at small sizes may not be of the right type. For example, there may be some monospaced font (that is very readable at small size) but you wouldn't want to use that for the running text. FWIW: Usually sans seriffed fonts require less horizontal space than seriffed fonts because they lack serifs. This is one of the reasons why some authors use them in captions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a font selection but not using a specific font in TeX

Answer (score 4):

You ask for a font that's usable with LaTeX, but nowadays that's *any* font in TrueType/OpenType format. Just use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTex, they are both perfectly capable of using those fonts, including font-specific variants.

There's one font I think is very legible at small sizes, because it's designed to be used in small print: [Bell Centennial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_Centennial)

[image: Bell Centennial]

Comment: Which is a commercial and not a free font.

Comment: @percusse True, but the OP didn't ask for a free font in the question, or am I wrong?

Comment: this is a marvelously legible font at small sizes, with no confusion between "Eye", "ell" and "one" or "Oh" and "zero".  it is eminently suitable for catalogs and directories and well worth the investment, but there are absolutely no math facilities.

Comment: Well I can go to myfont site and select the appropriate filters myself then no? What's the point of TeX then?

Comment: @percusse I really don't understand your question about the point of TeX and its relevance to this answer about a font which should be legible at small sizes.

Comment: I mean if a commercial solution is a viable solution then all the fonts in the myfonts catalogue are too. So that doesn't help because majority of those fonts are commercial and expensive. So your answer can simply be *buy one*. However, other than that the question itself must go to Graphic Design.SX anyway. This has nothing to do with TeX.

Comment: @percusse Yes, that way. I agree that this question has nothing to do with TeX (but about $ 30 for a font is not *that* expensive, [these](http://www.teff.nl) are way more expensive) (remark 2: it's strange that Adobe fonts are cheaper in USD than EUR).

Answer (score 4):

Bitstream Charter was developed for small resolutions and is not as weak as CMR or Latin Modern. Furtermore, Charter is supported by Latex, e.g. through xcharter or mathdesign.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitstream_Charter

ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/fonts/xcharter/doc/xcharter-doc.pdf

[image]
<sub>(source: [ctan.org](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/documentation/Free_Math_Font_Survey/images/chartermd.png))</sub>

Comment: That image is not from Charter but Times (like) font.

Comment: That font looks like Charter to me.

Comment: The greek characters are not of Charter, at least they don't exist in the free font version of (Bitstream) Charter or XCharter.

Comment: Ah, in the [accompanying pdf](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/documentation/Free_Math_Font_Survey/survey.pdf) one can see that the font used for Greek symbols is ‘Math Design’.

Comment: Upon further inspection, the math doesn't look like Charter to me, but the other text does. I like this Math Font though

Answer (score 1):

You can look at a few fonts at [this catalog](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/alphfonts.html) and then choose one. I, personally, think that Latin Modern, Paratype Sans Narrow, Roboto Light Condensed, etc, might be good for what you need. For all of them, once you click in the name of the font and go down the page, there's the link for the font page at CTAN, where you can make the download.

Comment: That page doesn't say which fonts are scalable. Those are only the types.

Comment: But shows what fonts are smaller than others, so that must help something, no?

Comment: depends what OP wants.

Comment: Ok, you won. If he says it doesn't help, I'll just erase it.

Comment: No no, don't get me wrong, I think OP is trying to scale something like a table or similar. But you can use any system font via `fontspec` package using Xe- or LuaTeX engine.

Comment: @percusse The font catalogue does say whether the font is available in type 1 format. In the vast majority of cases, at least, if it is not available in type 1 format, it is not going to be scalable. [That is, truetype and opentype fonts are mostly off-topic as far as the catalogue is concerned because they cannot be used with standard TeX, and only the former can be used directly with pdfTeX, such usage being itself quite rare.]

Comment: @cfr Depends also on the encoding you are using. The font itself is rarely informative enough about the typeset version of it in a particular context.

Comment: @cfr But is that an actual demand of the OP (that the font is available in T1 format)? They can use Xe(La)TeX or Lua(La)TeX and typeset documents using OpenType fonts.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel Not that I know of, no. I don't think the OP expressed a preference one way or the other, did they? My point was that otf/ttf were off-topic for the font catalogue - not for this question. I was just pointing out that, generally, the font catalogue does tell you whether a font is available in a scalable format or not since it tells you whether it is available in type 1 format or not. For the purposes of the catalogue, fonts have scalable versions more-or-less if, and only if, a type1 version is to be had.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some good options that I found.

[image: Computer Modern Bright]

[image: Roboto Light]

Comment: Won't these fonts get to thin when printed at small sizes?

Comment: I used footnotesize and It was readable to me at those sizes.  I wanted something was readable, but also wouldn't take up a lot of space.

Answer (score 0):

To fill an area with as much letters as possible, you need a narrow running fonts, which is legible in small print. You'll find many narrow running fonts in the web.

But there are more factors: the solution of your printer, the paper, your eyes, the light.

If you can get things printed with a resolution of 2000 dpi on paper for scientific books, you'll be surprised what is still legible "ceteris paribus".

The usual printer with a solution of 1200 dpi at most is the limiting factor, IMO. So don't spent to much time and effort on the fonts.

I prefer serif fonts in small print and suggest to use Linux Libertine. There is a LaTeX package, probably you've already got it on your HD.